# Комментирование методов

Tags: java, javadoc

Допустим, есть класс, реализующий некий интерфейс. Где лучше писать комментарии к методам: в классе или в интерфейсе, или же и там, и там? Есть ли какие-либо рекомендации по этому поводу?

Comment: Если метод нуждается в комментариях - значит нужен рефакторинг. Целью которого является облегчение понимания его работы.

Comment: @VladVetrov здесь речь идет о генераторе документации JavaDoc на основе комментариев.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В интерфейсе всегда описываем, что реализуют наследники. Если у наследника нет отличий в деталях реализации от интерфейса, то ставим:

```
/**
  * {@inheritDoc}
  */
```

иначе более детально поясняем в комментарии.

Comment: @Ksenia поправил.

Comment: Только почему-то не находится комментарий из интерфейса: http://joxi.ru/Vm6vQZduDW3k5m Хотя я добавила комментарий к соответствующему методу интерфейса.